# Tuple compare in python

Tags: python, compare, tuples

I have I have simple code looking like:

```
>>> a = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
>>> b = ('2', '6')
>>> 
>>> def comp(list1, list2):
...     for val in list1:
...         if val in list2:
...             return True
...     return False
... 
>>> print comp(a, b)
True
```

Please help me understand why I receive "True"? And how I can find complete matching between two tuples?

Thank you.

Comment: At 2 in a, the function has been short-circuited and returned True. And it's ambiguous to say "find complete match", you mean a "intersection", with or without order preserved?

Comment: Can you describe your expected results? You want to check if one is a subset of the other? You want to see if both tuples contain exactly the same elements as each other?

Comment: When `val` is `'2'`, the condition `if val in list2` will match, and the function will immediately return true, because that is what you have written. If you wanted something else, you need to give a clearer description.

Comment: You should not do these things in the interactive interpreter. Write commands to a file, insert `print('val', val)` on the line above `return True` and you know why your "algorithm" returns `True`.

Comment: I expect to receive "True" when all elements of tuple "b" matches with tuple "a" and opposite some elements in tuple "b" didn't find in tuple "a" receive "False".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement return statement exits a function, optionally passing back an expression to the caller.

so if you write :

```
a = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
b = ('6', '2')

def comp(list1, list2):
    for val in list1:
        if val in list2:
            return True
    return False
print comp(a, b)
```

Answer would be `False`.
So solution :

```
a = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
b = ('2', '3')

def comp(list1, list2):
    for val in list1:
        if val not in list2:
            return False
    return True

print comp(b, a) # This will written True 
print comp(a, b) # This will written False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Change your code a little bit. May this will be of some help.

```
def comp(list1, list2):
    for val in list1:
        if val not in list2:
            return False
    return True
```